# ActionBar Layout overlapping while using Fragments

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar, fragment

I just noticed in my app I use the actionbar with the fragment, when I leave the app in the background for a while 'and reopen.
The various layout mingle happens a mess ... likely due to how I configured the class of the tab.
I write down here the source:

```
 private class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment mFragment;

    private final Activity mActivity;

    private final String mTag;

    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {

        mActivity = activity;

        mTag = tag;

        mClass = clz;

    }
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        // Check if the fragment is already initialized

        if (mFragment == null) {

            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity

            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());

            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);


        } else {

            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.show(mFragment);
            //ft.attach(mFragment);

        }

    }
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if (mFragment != null) {

            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached

           // ft.detach(mFragment);
            ft.hide(mFragment);
        }

    }
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

     //ft.replace(tab.getPosition(),mFragment);

        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }

}
```

This happens when I leave the app in the background for a while 'and in the meantime I use other ... I just can't figure out on what does it depends ... the ram? Have i done something wrong in the code?
Here is the screenshot for the same:
 http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/2406/dmc4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mention the following in your activity's tag in manifest:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: that: <activity
                android:name="com.megadonate.megadownloader.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/> ???????